# Erro ao fazer um Post

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando salvar as informações que vem do meu formulário de cadastro com essa função:

```
public function postCreate()
{

    $this->beforeFilter('csf', array('on' => 'post'));
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Despesa::$rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    unset($data['_token']);
    //dd($data);
    Despesa::create($data);
    return Redirect::route('admin.despesas');
}
```

Mas quando quando envio me dá um erro:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException

id

C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\Projetos\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php
{
    $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();
    foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value) {
        $key = $this->removeTableFromKey($key);
        if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
            $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
        } elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
            throw new MassAssignmentException($key);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se passa dados diretamente para o `Eloquent::create` você está fazendo um [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment), o mesmo é considerado inseguro pelo fato de que o usuário poderá inserir dados como quiser em sua tabela.

Para evitar que o Laravel detecte isso como uma falha de segurança você deve especificar quais campos podem ou não serem modificados diretamente, para isso adicione uma propriedade `$fillable` ou `$guarded`.

A `$fillable` representa os campos que podem ser modificados diretamente e o `$guarded` tem efeito contrário, exemplo:

```
<?php
class Model extends Eloquent {
    $fillable = array('nome','senha');
    $guarded  = array('id','codigo');
}
```

Quando eu usar `Eloquent::create` na minha model acima ela vai bloquear qualquer valor nos campos `id` e `codigo` e vai permitir modificação direta apenas dos campos `nome` e `senha`.

Comment: só não tinha adicionado nada em $fillable

Answer (score 1):

Em referência no próprio site [Laravel](http://www.laravel.com), o link [mass-assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) explica porque tal erro acontece

> When creating a new model, you pass an array of attributes to the model constructor. These attributes are then assigned to the model via mass-assignment. This is convenient; however, can be a serious security concern when blindly passing user input into a model. If user input is blindly passed into a model, the user is free to modify any and all of the model's attributes. For this reason, all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

***Tradução Site Google***

> Ao criar um novo modelo, você passar uma matriz de atributos para o construtor do modelo. Esses atributos são então atribuído ao modelo via mass-atribuição. Isto é conveniente; no entanto, pode ser um problema sério de segurança quando cegamente passando a entrada do usuário em um modelo. Se a entrada do usuário é passada cegamente em um modelo, o usuário é livre para modificar qualquer e todos os atributos do modelo. Por esta razão, todos os modelos eloqüentes proteger contra mass-assignment por padrão.

Para definir esse tipo de configuração segue exemplo básico:

```
class Carro extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('cor', 'modelo');
}
```

***Referência:***

- http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment
- http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent
- http://laravel.com